# Google Chrome extension run as if in console?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, deezer

I'm trying to make a Google Chrome extension that pauses/plays the payer in DEEZER (www.deezer.com). I i manually run the code "`playercontrol.doAction('next')`" in the Google chrome JavaScript console, I can manipulate the deezer player, so i looked at the possibility of injecting the code into the Deezer web page with an extension but I haven't managed to do so successfully.
Is it possible to run JavaScript code in Deezer web page as if it were coming from the console in Google Chrome?
If so how?

Comment: Do you mean Java or JavaScript? Is there a Java applet somehow involved here?

Comment: Sorry, yes, i mean javaScript.

Comment: I suspect you're looking for either [content scripts](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts.html) or [`chrome.tabs.executeScript`](http://developer.chrome.com/extensions/tabs.html#method-executeScript).

Comment: Thank you very much, I'll research that. Do i execute the "chrome.tabs.executeScript" code from the background.js file or any other file declared in the manifest.json?

Comment: I used the executeScript methode and it sort of worked but i get the error "Uncaught ReferenceError: playercontrol is not defined".

Comment: possible duplicate of [Building a Chrome Extension - Inject code in a page using a Content script](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9515704/building-a-chrome-extension-inject-code-in-a-page-using-a-content-script)

Answer (score 6):

The problems that you are facing here are the following:

1. You need to use content_scripts instead of running code from the background page.
2. Code run from the background page and code run as content scripts are "Sandboxed". This means that your code doesn't have access to the global variables created by the page. Your extension doesn't have access to it. THE GOOD NEWS IS that you can still do it. You have to be clever, though.

In your extension, you have to inject a new Script tag into the "head" of the page. You have to create a new script tag and append it to the head of the page. Before you append it, you need to set the "innerHTML" of the script tag to be the JavaScript that you want to run. Here is the gist of what you need to do.

```
var myJavaScript = "alert('hey guys');";    //You need to put your JS here. 
var scriptTag = document.createElement("script");
scriptTag.innerHTML = myJavaScript;
document.head.appendChild(scriptTag);
```

This will put the new script tag into the head, which bypasses the security of the Chrome Extension. This will give the new script access to the regular global variables on the page, ie: you will have access to the 'playercontrol' object.

Comment: I have been sitting with this issue for a long time now and this worked as a charm for me!

I was trying to access React properties of a select html field, but Object.getOwnPropertyNames only returned the HTML option elements, and not the __reactEventHandlers-properties etc. Massive headache! Works with your snippet here.

Answer (score 1):

This feature has been deprecated by Chrome's security policy.